# ASP.NET MVC RewritePath from a Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a url rewrite from within my controller.

I've been able to achieve this from `Application_BeginRequest` but I require some dependencies at the controller level to make a decision on whether to do the rewrite.

I have tried from the controller, but it doesn't have any effect.

Is is possible to do a url rewrite from the controller?

Note that I need to preserve the original URL.

Comment: Have you tried to do it from Routing?

Comment: URL rewriting takes the incoming URL from the request and rewrites it to something else before passing it on to the handler, which is handy if you need the server to *serve a different file* than what was requested. Routing maps a URL *directly* to a handler (an MVC controller action method). MVC is not file-system based, so there is no need to *rewrite* the URL, but it does allow you to specify the URL as anything you like using routing. Why not just cut out the middle-man and use routing?

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I need to preserve the original URL. If a user navigates to /controller/ActionA, I need to preserve the url they've navigated to.

Answer (score 0):

Well,the questioni is a little weird,because the route action should be occured before execute to controller level.
If you really wanto do something like affecting rewrite in controller,you can do it like below:

```
file controller.cs

void func(){
//do rewrite when application begin to request,via make a flag
//1 means yes,0 means no
application["do_rewrite"] = 1;
}

file application.cs
void Application_BeginRequest(){
  if(application["do_rewrite"] == 1){
  //do rewrite
  }
}
```